# How to get Background Color of currently selected item from ListView in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, android-listview

Can anyone tell me how to get background color of selected item from `ListView` in android?
Here I an using `ListView` with multiple item select mode and I just want to set background color of selected items. If user unchecked the option I want to restore it's background color to black.

I can set the background color of selected items but I am not getting the current background color of selected item.

Please help me.

I am using Android 4.0.3 and editor Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you should maintain a boolean variable for each item initially with false and when you click on any item you should make the variable to true.

and in getView() of your custom adapter you check whether it is true or false and do the needfull.

before trying this have a xml file in drawable folder and set it as background if this doesn't work then do the above must work..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- touch down -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <!-- selected -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_selected"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"/>
</selector>
```

Refer this [LINK](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/03/customized-listview-items-selection.html)  [LINK](http://bestsiteinthemultiverse.com/2009/12/android-selected-state-listview-example/)

Comment: thanks for quick response.It require extra memory space and I don't want that.Any other idea?

Comment: > It require extra memory space. I don't feel it would effect performance any how using this approach. The approach of applying selector as a background is more clean and preferred

Comment: Thanks for your support.I found another solution.Thanks anyway.